# Getting NaN when adding variables which consists of another variables

Tags: javascript, nan

```
var dml = 30
var dd = parseFloat(document.getElementById("DriverD").value)     <----- Only numbers like 10
var dm = dd-dml

alert((dd - dml) * 0.75)    <----- This works
alert(dm * 0.75)            <----- This returns NaN
alert(typeof(dm))        <----- This show that dm is a Number
```

I'm not sure why I keep getting NaN. I already tried `parseFloat` and `parseInt` but still showing NaN when multiplying a variable (dm) which consists of variables (dd-dml). dm is the result of subtracting dml with dd or 10-30. Please share your solutions.

I'm new here and I need help, please don't troll :) I am trying to add a cost calculator to my website.

Comment: `typeof NaN` is also `"number"`, could you `alert(dm)` instead of the last?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HfCrD/

Comment: What is the **real** value of `DriverD` element

Comment: DriverD is a textbox and I am using 10 during troubleshooting of this issue. My website is a simple html/javascript site.

Comment: @user1914656 Can you re-create the problem on JSFiddle or link to a live version we can see?

Comment: I GOT IT! HOW STUPID OF ME. ON MY ACTUAL WEBSITE I DECLARED DM FIRST BEFORE DD AND DML. WORKS FINE NOW THANKS GUYS! :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine to me.

I want to tell another possible problem: You dont check if `document.getElementById("DriverD").value` is a number or not. If a user enters a string or other type, it will cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will put error handler for that in the future :) but for now I am using the number 10 while troubleshooting this matter.

Comment: I wish I could help. But haven't used javascript.

Comment: I GOT IT! HOW STUPID OF ME. ON MY ACTUAL WEBSITE I DECLARED DM FIRST BEFORE DD AND DML. WORKS FINE NOW THANKS GUYS! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Two operands must be convert to parseFloat

```
<input type="text:" value="10" id="DriverD" />

var dml = parseFloat(30);
var dd = parseFloat(document.getElementById("DriverD").value);
var dm = dd-dml;
alert(dm * .10);
```

Result is -.2

Comment: Sorry, still getting NaN when doing alert(dm * .10) :( it does not return NaN when doing alert((dd-dml)*.10) though

Comment: Pls reload your browser(ctrl+shft+R)

Comment: I GOT IT! HOW STUPID OF ME. ON MY ACTUAL WEBSITE I DECLARED DM FIRST BEFORE DD AND DML. WORKS FINE NOW THANKS GUYS! :D

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you could get `NaN` here is that the value of `dd` is `NaN`. Because the value of `dm` is defined as `dd - dml` and the value of `dml` is a `Number` value, `30`.

`parseFloat()` always returns a `Number` value. The `-` operator converts its operands to `Number` only if necessary. So the value of `dm` must by definition be a `Number` value.

However, `NaN` is a `Number` value (`typeof NaN === "number"`), and it is "toxic": once an operand is `NaN`, the result of all following arithmetic operations is `NaN`.

That means that `parseFloat()` must have returned `NaN`, which means that the argument to `parseFloat()` could not be interpreted as the prefix of a decimal number representation.

One common reason for that is that the user has typed thousands separators (which are not supported) or a decimal comma while only a decimal point is supported.

Comment: My bad is that I declared dm first (var dm = dd - dml) before declaring dd and dml so it's like doing var dm = null - null. It works fine now, I rearranged the order of my declarations.:)

Comment: In that case it is equivalent to `var dm = undefined - undefined` where the right-hand side is equivalent to `Number(undefined) - Number(undefined)`, `NaN - NaN` and finally `NaN`. Variable instantiation happens before variable initialization. Variables are instantiated with the `undefined` value of the `Undefined` type, not the `null` value of the `Null` object type.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** **this one**

```
    var dml = 30;
    var dd = parseFloat(document.getElementById("DriverD").value)   ;  <----- Only numbers like 10
    var dm=0;
    dm = dd-dml;

    alert((dd - dml) * 0.75);    <----- This works
    alert(dm * 0.75);            <----- This returns NaN
    alert(typeof(dm));        <----- This show that dm is a Number
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie but I think it is the type error, solution:

```
var someV  = parseInt(document.getElementById("some-v-id").value, 10) || 0,
```

parseInt(value, 10) - you know because you used parse float, but two pipes and zero might prevent you from NaN as JavaSrcipt might be treating 0 as a string.